# Some events are not available when the EventBridge rule triggers the push to SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-event-bridge

I have an EventBridge rule that gets triggered on the insert and update of a specific item type. The data that satisfies the rule is then pushed to an SQS queue, which in turn triggers a Lambda function. Lately, I have been observing that not all events are available in the SQS queue. Sometimes the insert event doesn't come through, and sometimes the modify event doesn't either.
what can be done in this case ?

Comment: If you are using the SQS event mapping for AWS Lambda, your Lambda will be passed a *list* of SQS messages. Are you sure you are processing all the events in the list? It is a common mistake to write Lambda functions that only process one SQS message and exit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up a DLQ on the target configuration (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-rule-dlq.html)?

Comment: yes I have DLQ set up, Events are not failing either.